# Multiple Scroll Based Website

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

So Im working on a **Website Which Scrolls in different directions** without any Horizontal Scrollbar Which looks like this **https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex2Bf.jpg** 
To make it easier its a onepage website as i scroll down it will scroll `vertically` and then `horizontally` towards right , then `diagonally` towards left and at last `vertically` towards bottom..
I just wanted to know wether this kind of  scrolling is possible or not .. i Saw a plugin `ScrollTo` which functions the same but by clicking and even horizontal scrollbar appears ..i want it to happen while scrolling 
and without any horizontal scrollbar...
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you may be looking for jQuery Scroll Path Plugin

**[DEMO](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)** | 
**[Github Page](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath)**

another useful plugin [**superscrollorama**](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

Comment: i think this is what i want but how do i generate that path which i want??

Comment: @ezaz https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath check here "Drawing the Path" section